# i have search method in my class and i want to check size of lastname>0 if >0 than work assert method but not working

Tags: trigger, unit-test

```
 static testMethod void unitTest3(){
     Test.StartTest();
     Contact c=new Contact();
     c.LastName='indora';
     insert c;
     contactcloudcontroller objccc=new contactcloudcontroller();
     Contact con=[select id,AccountId from contact where id=:c.id];
     objccc.con.lastname='test';

     objccc.search();
     System.Assert(objccc.con.lastname.size()>0);
     Test.StopTest();
 }
```

Comment: one simple question can we check `string.size()` ? `size()` method available for list. If you want to check string size then use `string.length()`

Comment: Also, pasting the actual error message will help us help you better :)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't updated `objccc` after setting the lastname. That is why the lastname is empty.

Comment: mkorman - Can we check `string.size()` ?

Comment: Well spotted. It has to be string.length()